# Search Issue - Way to search multiple table fields in access

Tags: ms-access

Bit of an access noob I'm afraid and while I'm plugging my way through most problems that have been thrown up thanks to a couple of reference texts I have I can't really get my head around this.

The database is used to keep a track of ongoing projects. The table in question refers to a site where the project is happening and contains three fields for supply numbers. I need to be able to enter a single supply number in a text box on the front page and match it to the site etc. before displaying the results.

All of the forms, tables etc. are in place it's just performing the search I'm stuck on.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 0):

The simplest case would be something along the lines of the following (assuming that "supply numbers" are alphanumeric)

```vbs
Dim strSupplyNumber As String, strSQL As String
strSupplyNumber = Replace(Me.txtSupplyNumber.Value, "'", "''")
strSQL = _
        "SELECT * FROM [Sites] " & _
        "WHERE [SupplyNumber1] = '" & strSupplyNumber & "' " & _
            "OR [SupplyNumber2] = '" & strSupplyNumber & "' " & _
            "OR [SupplyNumber3] = '" & strSupplyNumber & "' "
```

where `txtSupplyNumber` is the name of the text box control on the "front page" form.

You could then use the `strSQL` string as the `Record Source` of another form, or use it in an `OpenRecordSet` method, or whatever your next step requires.